# Kendo MVC - Export to Excel

Tags: excel, razor, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo mvc grid and I am trying to export data to excel.

This is my .chhtml.

```
<div class="panel-body table-responsive">
    @{
        var gridBuilder = CodeTaskKendoGrid.CreateTaskGrid(Model.TaskOverviewList, Model.ViewableExtraFields, this.Html, Model.Configuration);

        gridBuilder.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
            .Excel(excel => excel
                .AllPages(true)
                .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Task"))
            );
    }
    @gridBuilder.ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")

</div>
<script id="client-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
# if (SubTasks != null && SubTasks.length > 0) { #
<text>

    <table class="adra-kendo-table">
        # var j = SubTasks.length; #
        # for(var i = 0; i < j; i++) { #
        # var ownerName= SubTasks[i].OwnerName; #
        # var taskStatusId= SubTasks[i].TaskStatusId; #
        # var taskId = SubTasks[i].Id; #
        # var periodId = SubTasks[i].PeriodId; #
        # var teamId = SubTasks[i].TeamId; #
        <tr>
            <td>#: SubTasks[i].Id #</td>
            <td>#: SubTasks[i].Name #</td>

            <td class="# @CodeTaskKendoGrid.OwnerClass("ownerName") #"># @CodeTaskKendoGrid.OwnerName("ownerName") #</td>
            <td>#: SubTasks[i].TaskStatus #</td>
            <td>#: SubTasks[i].ApprovalStatus #</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="/Task/EditTask?taskId=#=taskId#&amp;periodId=#=periodId#&amp;teamId=#=teamId#" type="button">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>

        # } #
    </table>

</text>
# } #
```

And this is where I generate the grid (this is another .cshtml file and I am using this to generate t the grid. I call the method in this file from the above file)

```
public static GridBuilder<DtoTaskExtended> CreateTaskGrid(IEnumerable<DtoTaskExtended> taskList, IEnumerable<DtoExtraField> viewableExtraFields , System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TaskGridConfig gridConfig)
{

    ExtraFieldConfigs = viewableExtraFields;
    Helper = htmlHelper;
    GridConfig = gridConfig;
    var retObj = Helper.Kendo().Grid(taskList)

        .Name("AdraKendoGrid")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .Read(read => read.Action("GetTaskResult", "Task"))
        )

        .Columns(ColumnsConfigurator)
        .Groupable(gr => gr.Messages(message => message.Empty(Strings.kendoGroupMsg)))
        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 15, 50, 100, 500 })
            .Info(true)
            .Messages(message => message.Display("{0} - {1} " + Strings.of + "{2} " + Strings.items))
            .Messages(message => message.ItemsPerPage(Strings.itemsPerPage))
            .Messages(message => message.Empty(Strings.noItemsToDisplay)))
        .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
        .Sortable()
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))

        .ColumnMenu();



    return retObj;
}
```

And finally, this is my controller action supposed to be called from the excel import button.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Excel_Export_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
    {
        var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);

    }
```

But this controller action does not even get called when click the Excel Import button in the grid.

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated. 
Thank you.

After specifying this

```
.ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
        .Excel(excel => excel
            .AllPages(true)
            .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Task"))
        );
```

and creating relevant Action Methods, should I do anything more?

I have tried lot of examples, but my button (Export to Excel) button does not do anything. I have imported the jsZip.js file (as specified in Kendo Demo) as well. I am following the below examples.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/excel-export

Any kind of help is appreciated. I am stucked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Kendo MVC version I was using. Excel export is supported from the Kendo 2014 Q3 (2014.3.1119) version.

Answer (score 1):

One solutions is:

```js
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
```